# Does IQueryable re-query the database on every access of the object?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I had a bug in my code and eventually managed to track it down to my usage of an IQueryable statement, however the implication of what happened leaves me with a few questions I was hoping someone with more knowledge on Entity Framework could shed some light on so I can improve going forward.

(N.B. This code was originally in a single foreach loop, but I was getting a bug there too, though I'm not sure if its the same one)

```
IQueryable<SystemOrder> Orders = _ctx.SystemOrder.Where(x => x.ordStatus == 1 && x.rctStatus == 0).OrderBy(x => x.Id);

            Console.WriteLine(Orders.Count());

            AddressLabel l;

            foreach (SystemOrder Order in Orders)
            {
                Order.rctStatus = 1;
            }
            _ctx.SaveChanges();

            foreach (SystemOrder Order in Orders)
            {
                l = new AddressLabel(Order);
                SendOrderConfirmationEmail(Order, l);
                Order.rctStatus = 2;
            }
            _ctx.SaveChanges();

            foreach (SystemOrder Order in Orders)
            {
                l = new AddressLabel(Order);
                CreateOrderFiles(Order, l);
                Order.rctStatus = 3;
            }
            _ctx.SaveChanges();

            foreach (SystemOrder Order in Orders)
            {
                SystemOrder result = PushToTill(Order);
                Order.ordStatus = result.ordStatus;
            }
            _ctx.SaveChanges();
```

So the issue was that the results only worked in the first foreach loop, and all subsequent loops were ignored as the "Orders" IQueryable returned no results.  I was confused until it dawned on me that it might be running the query each time orders was accessed, as it was not in-memory.  Pushing the results to a list and working on that avoided the issue.

So if this is the case I have a few questions:

1. Is my assumption actually correct in that each foreach is requerying the database?
2. Would this not happen if the code was contained within a single foreach?
3. In situations like this, what would be the best approach?  Using memory or multiple queries?

The reason that I needed separate foreach loops is so I could call SaveChanges() on each status update as you can't call it within the loop.  Inefficient but I wasn't sure of the best approach under these circumstances.

Thanks :)

Comment: I've been saying this for over a decade but it bears repeating once again.  An object representing a query **represents a query**. It does not represent *the results of executing the query*. A query is a question, not an answer, and the same question can have two different answers if asked at two different times.

Comment: This is what I learnt yesterday :)  Makes sense really as if you aren't putting the object into memory, then it's not there when you ask for it.  Seems so obvious but threw me off for a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - Yes

2 - Yes, single foreach should work

3 - Not clear what is the situation, I think that using single foreach is a good solution

Comment: Thanks for confirming!  With regards to No.3 it's because I'm porting over legacy code which updates the db after each method runs to persist what stage the order is at through the automated system.  Of course I can't do that without calling SaveChanges and I have to do that outside the loop.  The original bug might be an effect of the database not getting the update until the end, so for this single instance I'm going to go with committing to memory and working on it from there.  I think I've overlooked something in the original code because this doesn't make a huge amount of sense!

Comment: Than if the data are not big, calling .ToArray() after first line should work

Answer (score 2):

> In situations like this, what would be the best approach? Using memory
>   or multiple queries?

Use whichever approach results in the most readable code.  If having multiple foreach loops makes your code more readable, replace

```
IQueryable<SystemOrder> Orders = _ctx.SystemOrder
    .Where(x => x.ordStatus == 1 && x.rctStatus == 0)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id);
```

With:

```
List<SystemOrder> Orders = _ctx.SystemOrder
    .Where(x => x.ordStatus == 1 && x.rctStatus == 0)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .ToList();
```

Calling `ToList()` hits the database (i.e., runs the query once).  Enumerating a `List<T>` will not hit the database.  Contrary to many people's intuition, materializing a query will not break `_ctx.SaveChanges()`.  In the context of change-tracking, materializing a query via `ToList()` is not especially different from materializing it via `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually how the solution was written ;)  Has the advantage of being more atomic than the single foreach